# How to use underscores when defining a class Swift

Tags: swift

So I am just trying to make a class that does not require labels to make a new object so it can be like this:

`var car = MakeCar(12,200)`

How would I do that?

Comment: `MakeCar(_ someValue: Int, _ someOtherValue: Int)`

Comment: Please read the [Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166) section of the Swift book. Note the subsection under "Omitting Argument Labels".

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
class MakeCar{
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
    init(_ x: Int, _ y: Int){
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}


var car = MakeCar(12, 200)
```

edit: removed optionals

Comment: Why make everything optional?

Comment: oh, sorry, I did that out of habit